# jQuery - get ID of element after paste event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After pasting text, I want to get the ID of the target div. Later the divs are generated dynamically, code does not work:

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvMRU/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">

<div class="entry" id="1" contenteditable="true">paste here</div>
<div class="entry" id="2" contenteditable="true">paste here</div>
<div class="entry" id="3" contenteditable="true">paste here</div>
<div class="entry" id="4" contenteditable="true">paste here</div>

 </div>
```

JS

```
$('.wrap').on("paste", function(){

    console.log("current box ID: " + $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try you're using parent class`.wrap` You need to use `.entry` class as you are pasting in that `div`

```
$('.wrap div.entry').on("paste", function(){   
    console.log("current box ID: " + $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

If `.entry` is created dynamically then you can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document.body).on('paste','.wrap .entry',function(){
    console.log("current box ID: " + $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bvMRU/1/)

Comment: but if .entry is created dynamically?

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the target of the event (which is where the event originated) and then find the `.entry` which wraps that. You can't necessarily look directly at the target if you want to support having any complex structure inside of the `.entry` elements.

```
$('.wrap').on('paste', function(event){
  console.log('paste id: ' + $(event.target).closest('.entry').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you're attaching the event against the "container". I believe you have 2 options

```
$('.wrap').on("paste", function(e){

    console.log("current box ID: " + e.target.id );
});
```

or

```
$('.entry').on("paste", function(e){

    console.log("current box ID: " + this.id );
});
```

I'd go with the second option since it's more more clear to attach the event direclty to relevant elements instead of doing it to the container and use the `e.target` approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the event to the wrap div, so that's what `this` means for in the callback.

Change your event binding to:

```
$('.wrap .entry').on("paste", function(){
    console.log("current box ID: " + $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with this (just a little less code, but not much -

```
$('.entry').on("paste", function(e){
    console.log("current box ID: " + this.id ); // this.id is all you need to get any current id
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you binded the 'paste' event on the wrap class (which doesn't got an attribute id) you get a NULL.

You have to bind it you your entry fields, which have the id attribute.

```
$('.wrap .entry').on("paste", function(){
    console.log("current box ID: " + $(this).attr("id") );
});
```